# Is PHP detecting a wrong timezone for Berlin?

Tags: php, timezone

The code block should be able to speak for itself. The timezone `Europe/Berlin` is detected as `+02:00` but behaves like `+01:00`. When I specifically use `+02:00` as timezone, it works as expected. Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

```
>>> $timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')
=> DateTimeZone {#2356
     timezone: Europe/Berlin (+02:00),
   }
>>> $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', '2020-02-29T07:30:00.000+0100')
=> DateTime @1582957800 {#2349
     date: 2020-02-29 07:30:00.0 +01:00,
   }
>>> $timestamp->setTimezone($timezone)
=> DateTime @1582957800 {#2349
     date: 2020-02-29 07:30:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+01:00),
   }
```

```
>>> $timezone = new DateTimeZone('+02:00')
=> DateTimeZone {#2371
     timezone: +02:00,
   }
>>> $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', '2020-02-29T07:30:00.000+0100')
=> DateTime @1582957800 {#2364
     date: 2020-02-29 07:30:00.0 +01:00,
   }
>>> $timestamp->setTimezone($timezone)
=> DateTime @1582957800 {#2364
     date: 2020-02-29 08:30:00.0 +02:00,
   }
```

Comment: Have you taken daylight saving time into account?

Comment: `2020-02-29` is not during Central European Summer Time and is +01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berlin uses a UTC offset of `+01:00` during standard time (known in English as Central European Time, or CET), and `+02:00` during daylight saving time (known in English as Central European Summer Time, or CEST).  [Reference here.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin)

In the first example, you apply Berlin time to `2020-02-29` when CET was in effect, not CEST.  Thus you see a `+01:00` offset in the result.  This is correct.

In the second example, you are not applying Berlin time, but rather using applying a time zone with a fixed offset of `+02:00`, so you see that in the result.

See also the section titled "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).